# Django Reverse Inverse

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-views, django-urls, django-unittest

Is there an inverse method for Django's `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`?

I want a function `f(x)` such that `f(django.core.urlresolvers.reverse('shadowfax')) == 'shadowfax'`.

Does anybody have anything to say on whether this would be a proper approach to writing unit tests for methods that call `.reverse()`?

Comment: What is the usecase? You can always use url names to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably shocking:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.resolve( "/test" ).url_name
```

It is perfectly good way to use it and it is even recommend in the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/

Answer (score 1):

An updated version.

```
from django.urls import resolve
resolve( "/test" ).url_name
```